# How to run query automatically on a given database ( SQL ALCHEMY )

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I'm building a project using jinja2 for python & sql alchemy, and i would want the database to modify its own data at specific time. I had a hard time googling it because i've never done it before, so i don't properly know what to search in the first place.

To be a bit more concrete, let's say i'm selling products that got an expiration date. I would like my database to delete every products when the expiration date is past today.

What should i look for, and how do i even start to do this kind of thing, using python ( jinja2 ) & sql alchemy ? thanks for any references and/or global comprehension about this !

Comment: Try searching stackoverflow for something like 'update database from scheduled task'.  Usually you do these updates by adding a job to the operating system's task scheduler.

Comment: Instead of hard deletes with a scheduler, an alternative pattern is to have an `expires_at` column, and apply a default filter on that column against the current time whenever you query your products table.

Comment: @univerio it's simply an example, actually i would like to change the product state ( which is a column ) from "AVALAIBLE" to "EXPIRED"

Comment: I am with univerio: Add a column `EXPIRATION_DATE` and create a view simulating the product state using `IF` and `CURRENT_DATE`. Access that view via SQL Alchemy.

Comment: @flaschbier thanks you for answering, please consider fully read my answers before posting tho, i'm not saying anything against those methods but this is not what im looking for

Comment: Celery might be way to go here.http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: We are suggesting using an expiration column because it's much, *much* simpler and more robust (but slightly less flexible) than the alternative, which is to set up something like celery or crond. For simple use cases like yours, I suggest going with the former. I know it sounds like we are not answering your question, but we are just giving you an alternative solution that will save you a lot of headache.